# KOMA-scripts' \makenote*{} in \newenvironment?

Tags: luatex, environments, koma-script, scrlayer-notecolumn

I am using KOMA-scripts' `\makenote*{}` command to make notes in the margin. Example:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage{fontspec,geometry}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[]{memoanmich}{Memo an mich selbst}{colback=black!15,colframe=black!80,fonttitle=\bfseries,left=0mm,right=0mm}{memoanmich}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=1.8cm, right=5.6cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 3cm, marginpar=5cm, footskip = 1cm}

\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}
    Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ 
\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}

test

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: \makenote* example]

The relevant code in this example:

```
\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}
    Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$
\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}
```

To make things more readable, I decided to introduce a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{mams}
{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}}
{\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}
```

and now my note commands look like this:

```
\makenote*{\begin{mams}
    Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$
\end{mams}}
```

## The question:

Is it possible to add the `\makenote*{}` command to my environment `mams` so that my note commands look like this:

```
\begin{mams}
    Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$
\end{mams}
```

or maybe like this:

```
\begin{mams}{Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$}
\end{mams}
```

## My attempts

### The package [environ](https://ctan.org/pkg/environ)

Instead of `\newenvironment`, I tried the following code:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{mams}{%
\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}%
\BODY
\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}}
```

The error I get:

> `Undefined control sequence. \begin {small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}\BODY`

### `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`

```
\newenvironment{mams}{\makenote*\begingroup\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}}
{\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}\endgroup}
```

The errors I get:

> ```
> LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{mams}.
> Extra \endgroup.
> ```

### `\newsavebox`

```
\newsavebox{\mymemobox}
\newenvironment{mams}[1]{\sbox\mymemobox{#1}}{\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}\usebox{\mymemobox}\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}}
```

The relevant note command now looks like this:

```
\begin{mams}{Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$}\end{mams}
```

This compiles without any errors but I don't get the note itself i.e. `tcolorbox` draws the colored box, the font is small (which means that the `\begin{small}` environment is active), the colored box is in the margin (which means that the `\makenote*{}` command works). The only thing missing is the note itself i.e.

> `Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$`

[image: Missing note contents]

Full code:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage{fontspec,geometry}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[]{memoanmich}{Memo an mich selbst}{colback=black!15,colframe=black!80,fonttitle=\bfseries,left=0mm,right=0mm}{memoanmich}


\newsavebox{\mymemobox}
\newenvironment{mams}[1]{\sbox\mymemobox{#1}}{\makenote*{\begin{small}\begin{memoanmich*}{}{}\usebox{\mymemobox}\end{memoanmich*}\end{small}}}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=1.8cm, right=5.6cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 3cm, marginpar=5cm, footskip = 1cm}

\begin{mams}{Some maths: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$}\end{mams}

test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xparse and the b argument type:

```
\documentclass[oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage{fontspec,geometry}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[]{memoanmich}{Memo an mich selbst}{colback=black!15,colframe=black!80,fonttitle=\bfseries,left=0mm,right=0mm}{memoanmich}

\usepackage{xparse} %no longer needed in next latex version
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mams}{b}
 {%
   \makenote*{%
    \small
     \begin{memoanmich*}{}{}
     #1
     \end{memoanmich*}}%
 }{}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=1.8cm, right=5.6cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 3cm, marginpar=5cm, footskip = 1cm}

\begin{mams}
    Some maths: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$
\end{mams}
test

\end{document}
```